# Aggregation using conditions in CASE WHEN in SQL Teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata, aggregation

I work in SQL Teradata.

I have table like below:

```
client|currency|amount
------|--------|-----
1233  |CZK     |300.45
1233  |CZK     |100
4577  |EUR     |200.22
1233  |EUR     |500
```

I would like to count how many rows (clients) have rounded value in column "amount" (means for example 140.00 not 157.76 and so on). I use code like below:

```
sum(case when amount = floor(amount) then 1 else 0 end)
```

Nevertheless, O would like to do this operation separately for each currency, because above code give results without currency breakdown. How can I do that? I tried to use something like that, but it does not work: `sum(case when CUR_CODE ='EUR'and AMT_ORIG_CUR  = floor(AMT_ORIG_CUR) then 1 else 0 end)`

As a result I need table like below:

```
client   |sum_rounded_CZK|sum_rounded_EUR
---------|---------------|---------------
1233     |1              |1
4577     |0              |0
```

Comment: in this statement is error: sum(case when CUR_CODE ='EUR'and AMT_ORIG_CUR  = floor(AMT_ORIG_CUR) then 1 else 0 end) how to write thus statement with condition 'EUR' correctly ?

Comment: The sum(case) is valid SQL, what's the error message?